# Create certain amount of inline records for new record action (TCA / IRRE)

Tags: typo3

I have a backend form (e.g. Post), which includes an TCA (/ [IRRE](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html)) Inline field where other records (e.g. Comments) can be created.

What I now need is, that if a backend user creates a new record (Post), that at least 2 inline records (Comments) are created automatically, so the backend user does not have to click the "Create new" button for the Inline field two times.

Using [DataHandler](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/Database/Index.html) Hooks is no option here, because the backend user must fill out fields for the inline records before data get saved.

I debugged this down to the JavaScript function `inline.createNewRecord`, which is called when then the backend user clicks the "Create new" button for inline records. Calling this 2 times using JavaScript could be an option, but I hope, there may be a better solution

Comment: Hi derhansen did you end up using the javascript function?